# Chrome Extension sandbox and message passing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, eval, sandbox

I have an old Chrome extension that I want to update for manifest version 2. I noticed I have an `eval` function call that I cannot get rid of. I'm trying to understand the new Chrome sandbox feature that lets me do an `eval` call inside of it. The question is: by loading a sandbox page in the background, can I pass it a string containing something to execute, then have it executing the script, outputting the result on the popup page?

At first I thought this was possible but looking at the examples apparently the script to be evaluated has to be already in the sandbox page.

Thanks